# how to keep alive and executed telethon + flask

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio, telethon

i'm starting to learn about telethon, i have a userbot mounted in cpanel, i'm trying to get both flask and bot running all the time but i haven't figured out how to keep both of them working.

my code:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
import asyncio
from flask import Flask

api_id = 
api_hash = ''
string = 'SessionString'
client = TelegramClient(StringSession(string), api_id, api_hash).start()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def index():
    return 'index page'

async def main():
    await client.send_message('me', 'telethon : I\'m alive ')
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats ="me"))
    async def handler(event):
        await client.send_message('me', event.message)   
        if event.message.photo:
            if (event.message.message.find('text') != -1):
                await client.send_message('me', "text")
                messageId = str(event.message.photo.id)
                messageDate = event.message.date
                # messagePhotoPath = await event.message.download_media(file="./media")
                rawText = event.message.message
                posText = rawText.find('text')
                await client.send_message('me', "text"+posText)
                messageText = event.message.message[posText:6]
            else:
                await client.send_message('me', "text")
                # await client.send_message('me', messageText)
                # await client.send_message('me', "text' + str(event.message.photo.id))
                 # await client.send_message('me', await event.message.download_media(file="./media"))
                # print('File saved to', path)  # printed after download is done

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run_until_complete(main())
    app.run()
```

It should be clarified that the code without the flask works for me,

when I put the flask, the flask works for me and even the same telethon code but it dies, that is, it does not keep running

what I'm looking for is that both flask and the code are permanently running and listening

Comment: one of them run in separated thread - using module `threading`

Comment: I suggest looking into `asyncio`-based alternatives to Flask, such as Quart. You will have an easier time. Otherwise, try learning to use `threading` and `asyncio` together *before* attempting to use libraries using them. If you don't have that understanding it won't be easy.